# How to display lines in a file like ls displays files in a directory?

Tags: files, ls, cat

I have a long file with short lines (one word) `f` that I would like to inspect.
It would fit on the screen if it wasn't for the newlines.

If the data was already arranged in columns I could just do `column -t` but I want my one column to be split into many.

Knowing the length of the file I could just do:

```
$ sed -n  '1,10p' f > f1
$ sed -n '11,20p' f > f2
$ sed -n '21,30p' f > f3
$ sed -n '31,40p' f > f4
$ sed -n '41,50p' f > f5
$ paste f[1-5]
```

I imagine one could also make a new directory, apply `touch` on every line, do `ls`, delete the directory.

But is there an easy way to do this without creating any files?

Answer (score 10):

Oh, nevermind! `column` does that:

`column f` displays newline separated items in file `f` in columns, which has the same effect as `ls` on a directory.

Comment: @SaggingRufus I've edited my answer to include the exact command. As for how I came up with it, I had used `column -t` in the past to prettyprint files that were already organized into columns and tried `column` without parameters more to see what happens than because I expected it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, there's the `fmt` utility (check your local man page):

```
$ seq 100 > f
$ fmt --width 50 file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82
83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98
99 100
```

or [pr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html):

```
$ pr -15 -w 50 -a -s' ' -t file
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75
76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 10
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$ seq 20 > file
$ print -rC5 -- ${(f)"$(<file)"}
1   5   9   13  17
2   6   10  14  18
3   7   11  15  19
4   8   12  16  20
$ print -raC5 -- ${(f)"$(<file)"}
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
```